# Group input header parameters in Swagger UI using Java Spring Boot by type

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui

I'm developing a microservice using Java Spring Boot where my controller receives input parameters in the header. However, I don't want Swagger to display all 30 parameters in the UI. Instead, I want them to be grouped by type and displayed on the UI with a group heading. Alternatively, I want to provide a dropdown box where the user selects the type, and based on the selected type, the parameters are filtered/displayed in the UI while hiding the remaining parameters. This approach prevents the user from being confused with a large number of parameters. Also, I don't want to write separate methods in the controller.

Is it possible to group input parameters in Swagger UI using Java Spring Boot by type?

**I would like to group the parameters and tag them with a heading like this:
**

```
(FieldName) Type: Value

Heading: These 3 attributes are required for type Carrier
(FieldName) United_Count: 20
(FieldName) AmericanAir_Count: 30
(FieldName) Delta_Count: 30

Heading: These 3 attributes are required for type Model
(FieldName) Boeing_Count: 20
(FieldName) Jet_Count: 30
(FieldName) United_Count: 30 (common for two types)
```

Alternatively, I want to have a dropdown by type, and based on the selection, display the relevant parameters. For example:

Provide a dropdown in the UI Type By: Carrier, Model

For the selected type "Carrier", display the following input parameter names:

```
United: 20
AmericanAir: 30
Delta: 30
```

For the selected type "Model", display the following input parameter names:

```
Boeing: 20
Jet: 30
United: 30 (common for two types)
```

Thank you!